# window.location.href doesnt' work to redirect page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a custom HTML block to the page with the below code.
I created a Drop-down List and a search button for redirecting pages.
But it seems like that `window.location.href` doesn't work in WordPress.

Is there any way for adding the code to redirect the page?

```
<script>     
searchButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const selectedOption = filterSelect.value;
            if (selectedOption === 'newsports') {
                window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/';
            } else if (selectedOption === 'yahoo') {
                window.location.href = 'https://www.yahoo.com/';
            }
</script>
```

Comment: Leanne,  not exactly sure as we can't see how this code is added, but `filterSelect.value` are you certain that's not empty?  Can you add, immediately after the `click` listener, `console.log( filerSelect.value );` and the check your console to see if there's actually anything there?

Answer (score 1):

Your code only works on two conditions. Does not work any time neither of those two conditions are active.

But the proper way to redirect in WP is with the `wp_redirect()` function:

```
 wp_redirect('https://example.com/new-page', 301);
```

If you want to redirect inside your script, use this:

```
 window.location.replace("https://example.com/new-page");
```

Comment: She wants the redirect to happen based on user input, where they select from a dropdown and then they get redirected.  With `wp_redirect()` that's executed via PHP on the server, not client side.

Comment: True, but wouldn't the proper script command still be window.location.replace() ?

Comment: I believe they're interchangeable with the sole exception that `replace` doesn't add new additional records to the browsing history, but since this is redirecting someone based on their interaction, I don't think we're attempting to bypass a URL.  So really either should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your code missing `searchButton` and `filterSelect` variables and also JS code executes after the DOM has fully loaded try the below the script.

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        // Define the search button and filter select
        const searchButton = document.getElementById('searchButton');
        const filterSelect = document.getElementById('filterSelect');

        // Add click event listener to the search button
        searchButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            const selectedOption = filterSelect.value;
            if (selectedOption === 'newsports') {
                window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/';
            } else if (selectedOption === 'yahoo') {
                window.location.href = 'https://www.yahoo.com/';
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

please change as per your requirement HTML elements with IDs searchButton and filterSelect corresponding to your search button and dropdown list respectively.